# How to create a static library in Visual Studio 2008 with inl files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, static-libraries, inline-code

I am compiling a static library from a project that contains .h files for the interfaces and .inl files for the implementation and Visual Studio 2008 is not generating a .lib for me, what is the possible reason why?

Comment: What do you mean by "inl files"?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Those are files with .inl extension intended for inline definitions.

Answer (score 1):

If your library is a header-only library (everything is #included), then there's nothing to compile. Compilers only compile source code (.cpp files, .c, etc). If all of your code are templates, if your code doesn't have any .cpp files, then you're not generating any source. The user just includes some headers.

Most of Boost, for example, is header-only. You simply include it; you don't link to any of it.

To put it another way, if all of your code is inline, then none of it is *static*. So no static libraries.

Comment: +1 It sounds to me like there is no compiled code, so hence no .lib file

Answer (score 0):

The compiler treats .inl files the same way as it treats .h files - it doesn't compile them separately. You have to include them into a .cpp file to have them compiled.

Comment: Works, but causes this weird warning:
“warning LNK4221: no public symbols found; archive member will be inaccessible”